# "Flutter Unhandled Exception"

Tags: flutter, dart

Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException: writeFrom failed, path =
'C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Temp\flutter_tools.152371fb\flutter_tool.cf4f0aa7\app.dill' (OS Error: There is not
enough space on the disk.

, errno = 112)
#0      _checkForErrorResponse (dart:io/common.dart:55:9)
#1      _RandomAccessFile.writeFrom. (dart:io/file_impl.dart:884:7)

#2      _FileStreamConsumer.addStream...
(dart:io/file_impl.dart:218:21)

the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.
the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.

flutter clean
flutter run commands but not working

Comment: Seems liek your drive is full.  here is the message indicating 
There is not enough space on the disk.

Comment: Yup i agree with @HardikMehta , in the error log there's `(OS Error: There is not enough space on the disk.`. I think the solution is removing unused file to give some space for the disk. :)